# Create new dataframe from a subset dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,3,4,4), stockoprice1 = c(3,4,2,45,1))
```

And a second like this:

```
df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,4), name = c("price1","price2"))
```

I would like to merge them in order to take results like this:

```
> dfexpected = data.frame(id = c(1,1,3,4,4), stockprice1 = c(3,4,2,45,1), name = c("price1","price1",NA,"price2","price2"))
> dfexpected
  id stockprice1   name
1  1           3 price1
2  1           4 price1
3  3           2   <NA>
4  4          45 price2
5  4           1 price2
```

Which is the appropriate merge option?

Comment: @kath no it is not duplicate. non of this options can produce the results

Comment: Yes, what you are doing here is a left (outer) join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df = data.frame(id = c(1,1,3,4,4), stockoprice1 = c(3,4,2,45,1))

df2 = data.frame(id = c(1,4), name = c("price1","price2"))

dfexpected <- dplyr::left_join(df, df2)
dfexpected

#> Joining, by = "id"
#>   id stockoprice1   name
#> 1  1            3 price1
#> 2  1            4 price1
#> 3  3            2   <NA>
#> 4  4           45 price2
#> 5  4            1 price2
```

Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

you can use base `merge` while using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>% 
  merge(df2, by = "id", all = TRUE)

  id stockoprice1   name
1  1            3 price1
2  1            4 price1
3  3            2   <NA>
4  4           45 price2
5  4            1 price2
```

I love piped options, but base `merge` is really flexible for different kinds of joins by the options set from `all`, `all.x`, or `all.y`. It's easy to experiment to get the expected output.